# Problem with posting xml data to .net webservice asmx

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, jquery

I have the following code which is trying to post xml constructed data to webservice .asmx
but xml constructed data is not reaching webservice file at all.when i make ajax call control is not moving to webservice file at all.Is their any problem with syntax in ajax. 
This is my code on client side .

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false, 
                url: "/blkseek2/JsonWebService.asmx/GetList",
                datatype:"xml",
                data:"<?xml version='1.0'?><keyword1>"+keyword1+ "</keyword1><streetname>"+address1+ "</streetname><lat>"+lat+"</lat><lng>"+lng+ "</lng><radius>"+radius+"</radius>" ,
                contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
              //  processData: false,
                failure: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                     { ajaxError(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown); },
                success: function(xml) 
                 { ajaxFinish(xml); }



            });
```

This is my webmethod code in webservice which is trying to return xml file as output for the request

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]


public XmlDocument GetList(string keyword1, string streetname, string lat, string lng, string radius)
{
    XmlDocument xmldoc= CreateXML( keyword1,streetname,lat,lng,radius);


    return xmldoc;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call shouldn't be in XML format.

Change your data to something like this:

```
data:{ "keyword1:'" + keyword1 + "',streetname:'" + address1 + "',lat:" + lat + ",lng:" + lng + ",radius:" + radius}
```

EDIT: I just noticed your lat, lng and radius are strings (WHY?). Anyhow, because of that, try this:

```
data:{ "keyword1:'" + keyword1 + "',streetname:'" + address1 + "',lat:'" + lat + "',lng:'" + lng + "',radius:'" + radius + "'"}
```

Comment: I wouldnt say "shouldnt". Its bizarre, i agree - but its totally acceptable to post xml to a web service.

Comment: I've not seen a successful Jquery ajax call that works by posting the parameters in XML format. Mostly, because the Jquery API converts the "data" parameter to a query string.  You can send XML INSIDE a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,suggest me any if their are any good article which tries to post some data to webservice and get the reply back as xml file.

Comment: @mahesh Try changing datatype to dataType (notice the uppercase T)?
Also try this if you need to parse your XML: http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/